# How can I get the DirectoryIndex filename for a given URI using PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP program that has the user copying a URI into a text field. It then takes that text field and parses out the filename. The problem I'm having is if the user just puts "http://www.test.com/directory/" how can I tell if the file being served is index.php, index.html, etc etc? I tried using apache_lookup_uri, but it's not giving me the filename.

Thanks

Comment: I should have mentioned that the URIs are on the same server.

Comment: Then you should parse the server configuration files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

If the server is configured differently you can have files setup for directory index like `main.html` `jacko.asp` `iphone4.jsp`

Franky you only see on your end what parse_url gives you

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
   [scheme] => http
   [host] => hostname
   [user] => username
   [pass] => password
   [path] => /path
   [query] => arg=value
   [fragment] => anchor
)
```

/path

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same server you can look it up by hand in the conf files.

Or...

Create a dummy directory, having a dozen type of index files, each having as content their file name too. Make a request to the directory, and process the output. You have the server file name.