# How can I get Apache's DirectoryIndex in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, directoryindex

Is there a way to get an array (or something similar) of the DirectoryIndex in PHP being run under Apache? For example, I would like to be able check if one of the DirectoryIndex files exist in a specific directory. This is related to [How can I get the DirectoryIndex filename for a given URI using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121309/how-can-i-get-the-directoryindex-filename-for-a-given-uri-using-php) but it doesn't quite ask the same thing so please don't point to it despite its similarity.

EDIT: I'd prefer not to have to go file parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not, as Apache does not make it available through [environment variables](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/env_var.htm).

If you have control over the configuration you could use the [`setenv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html) directive alongside `DirectoryIndex`. Then read it in PHP using [`apache_getenv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php).

Otherwise I think you'll have to parse the Apache config files yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `DirectoryIndex` this way:

```
basename(apache_lookup_uri(realpath(urlencode('Path_directory_here')))->uri);
```

This method only works with Apache DSO module running.